# I'm on ubuntu 16.04 and, I installed xampp

Tags: xampp

When I'm trying to create file I'm getting this message

    `Warning: fopen("file.txt","w"): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/first/global.php on line 4 error`

How can i fix this?

Comment: Did you try sudo?

Answer (score 0):

Just install the LAMP-Stack with `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`. Plus, describe your 'question' better.